# Writing to a file in Tasklet step in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, io, spring-batch

My requirement is to write all the error records into a file after batch execution. Applications stores all error records in a Map and finally it needs to be written into a file.
After batch core step is done, I call this tasklet as a nextstep.
Is there a better way to write the records in the tasklet ? rather than traditional FileStreamWriter ?
Possible to use FileItemWriter inside tasklet?

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on how you store the records.  If you write them to a `List`, you could use a chunk based step with a `ListItemReader` and a regular `FlatFileItemWriter` as the writer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be write error file during batch processing and delete file in nextstep if it is empty a better approach?

I'm currently not using SB but I think you can also use a `FlatFileItemWriter` as listener for errors and set `shouldDeleteIfEmpty` property to let SB delete file automatically.
The only drawbacks for this solution are:

1. requires you to register `FlatFileItemWriter` as stream to let SB open/close correctly during chunk commit